# Sum of cells from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'price' looks like:

```
itemId, name, price, cover
1, Book, 30, paper
2, Phone, 100, box
3, Flower, 10, paper
```

And have a second table 'covers' looks like:

```
coverId, cover, price
1, paper, 5
2, box, 10
```

How can I get a return of items only with paper cover whis additional coloin of SUM (price of item + price of cover) ORDERred by SUM (price of item + price of cover), like this:

```
itemId, name, priceOfItemPluspriceOfCover
3, flower, 15
1, book, 35
```

Thank guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `inner join` will work

```
select p.itemId, p.name, p.price+c.price 
from price p 
inner join covers c on p.cover = c.cover 
Where c.cover = 'paper'
```

I would suggest you to store the `coverid` in price table instead of the cover name and define a foreign key to maintain the data integrity

Answer (score 2):

`select price.itemid, price.name, sum(price.price, covers.price) as priceOfItemPluspriceOfCover
from price
inner join covers
on price.cover = covers.cover`

Comment: get it, thanks for working and fast answer! That was all about that inner joint.